# AngularJS : assign variable reference to Object property

Tags: javascript, angularjs

As you can see in the code snippet below, `$scope.foo` is assigned on the `foo` property of the `$scope.bar` Object. Those are only in sync at initialization.
I would like to have a reference to `$scope.foo` in my `$scope.bar` Object to keep them synchronized.

Note :
This question is in an AngularJS context.
This is a trivial problem, and should be solved in JS frameworks.

Working solution in a Plunker : [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/N6MW4kTQORbYY33HdvLH?p=preview)

Snippet with the problem :

```js
angular.module('app', [])

.controller('Ctrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
 
    $scope.foo = "eeee";
    $scope.bar = {
        foo : $scope.foo
    };
    
    $scope.do = function() {
        alert($scope.foo);
    };
    
}]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="Ctrl">
    
    foo : 
    <input type="text" ng-model="foo"> {{foo}} <br />
    
    bar : 
    <input type="text" ng-model="bar.foo"> {{bar}} <br />
    
    
    <button type="button" ng-click="do()"> DO </button>
    
    
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Strings are immutable in javascript, and so when you do `foo : $scope.foo` you're assigning the value of the string to the object's property, and not a reference to `$scope.foo`.

The best way to keep them in sync is wrapping the string values in objects and use those to keep inter-references.

```js
angular.module('app', [])

.controller('Ctrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
 
    $scope.bar = {
        foo : {value: "eeee"}
    };
    $scope.foo = $scope.bar.foo;
    
    $scope.do = function() {
        alert($scope.foo.value);
    };
    
}]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="Ctrl">
    
    foo : 
    <input type="text" ng-model="foo.value"> {{foo.value}}<br />
    
    bar : 
    <input type="text" ng-model="bar.foo.value"> {{bar}} <br />
    
    
    <button type="button" ng-click="do()"> DO </button>
    
    
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: I understand immutable Object loose there reference every time they change, but I didn't ask this question in a pure JS environment. `foo` and `bar` are properties of the `$scope` Object, handled by the framework. This works, but I can't imagine using this pattern for a production app... I updated my question with a solution

Answer (score 0):

In Javascript, when you define an array during execution, variables are resolved at execution time:

```
$scope.foo = 5;
$scope.bar = {
    foo : $scope.foo
};
```

If you now do `$scope.foo = 7;`, `$scope.bar.foo` will still be `5`.

To access the fresh value, you can either access $scope.foo directly. If you must keep them in sync for some reason, you can use an Angular watch:

```
$scope.$watch('foo', function(newVal) { $scope.bar.foo = newVal; });
```

Note that such watch will be applied only in the next digest cycle (not immediately as you update `$scope.foo`). Also, the binding is one direction only.

Comment: I understand immutable Object loose there reference every time they change, but I didn't ask this question in a pure JS environment. `foo` and `bar` are properties of the `$scope` Object, handled by the framework. This works, but I can't imagine using this pattern for a production app... I updated my question with a solution